Pytest-mock patch method that sets attribute
assume there is some code sample
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # ..........
        self.conn_instance = get_conn_to_external_api(...)
        self.set_specific_attrs()
        # ..........
    def set_specific_attrs(self):
        self.attr1 = "some conn-depent-attr"
        self.attr2 = "another conn-depent-attr"
        #....
        self.attrn = "other attr"

In this case in init I can patch the connection as follows:
def test_something(self, mocker):
    mocker.patch("path-to-file/get_conn_to_external_api", some_patch_value)
    # ...
    instance = SomeClass()
    # testing code

How can I patch def set_specific_attrsto set arbitrary attributes, assuming it does not have return value and just does setattr ? Or alternatively, how can I patch attributes directly, so that in def test_something calling instance = SomeClass() would have patched attr1, attr2, ..., attrn ?
